# web view is not loaded in samsung galaxy s3

Tags: php, android, android-webview

I am unable to load php in web view  from server in samsung s3  ,where it is working fine in nexus 5.That php file  contains no of images. Is it a memory issue?Please help me to fix this issue.Please give some solutions..

Thanks in advance

```
    private void startWebView(String url) {
             webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            //enable JavaScript
             webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
                    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
                    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
                    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
                    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
                                    webView.loadUrl(url);
                   //enable zoom controls
                    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                                      }




 private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient 
            {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);

            }

 public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) 
            {

            if (progressDialog == null)
         {
                  progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(FooterDisplay.this);
                  progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                 progressDialog.show();
                 }
            }
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
           {
    try{
         if (progressDialog.isShowing()) 
                    {
               progressDialog.dismiss();
               progressDialog = null;
            }
        }catch(Exception exception)
            {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }



        }
@Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
    String description, String failingUrl)\
         {
    super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "could not be loaded",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the call to `view.loadUrl(url);` in your implementation of `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`. The load of the URL is already in progress, there is no need to start it again.

Comment: No its not working,ASctually i have 5 button which are loading 5 different php pages , but perticular one page is not loading , showing only blank screen ..   ksasq